# How does cross validation work for testing?

Tags: machine-learning

So I'm having some trouble on understanding how cross validation works in machine learning for model building.

Suppose I have a dataset with 100 samples, and I perform 10 fold cross validation.

From what I understand I'd split the dataset into sets of 10, and take 9 of those sets to train and test on one of those sets.

In the end, I would have 10 different classifiers, and prediction results for the entire dataset.

How would I then use these results to test on a new, 101th sample though?

Previously I was told that these 10 different classifiers were just averaged out, and the result is used to test on the new data point, but how exactly is this done? Are all 10 classifiers run on the new datapoint, and the confidence value at the end averaged out to get a final one which is used for classification? Or are the 10 generated classifiers somehow aggregated into one? I thought that it was the second case but now that I think about it I'm not sure how exactly you would "combine" different classifiers.

Answer (score 2):

The cross-validation is used to verify your learning-algorithm's ability to generalize to unseen data, i.e. if your cross-validation gives good results on your testing-folds.

Once this is established, you may use your entire training-set to train your model and apply it to new data.

What you are describing when you average 10 classifiers trained on different data sounds a bit like [Bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boosting_%28machine_learning%29) where you combine different weak learners into one strong learner. Note that this does mean different learners, not one learner trained on different data, usually.

Comment: OK, so suppose I'm using Weka to generate bayes net classifiers. What does the model that gets output by the cross validation setting mean then? Does that come from bootstrapping?

Answer (score 2):

Validation is used for model selection. If you have M canditate models, the one with the least classification error is m, where

```
0<m<=M
```

, the out-of-sample error won't exceed the validation error Eval plus

```
sqrt(log(M)/K)
```

, in your case K=N/10.

Cross validation is used to average the 10 obtained validation errors as the Eval.

Once the model m is determined, you will use all of your sample data for the training process.